# Latency Spike in Forced C# Garbage Collection with GC.Collect

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, latency

I am profiling the performance of a dedicated program for processing large amounts of latency sensitive market data events.  One of the constraints of the project is to restrict the latency of event reactions to less than 1 second.  Since the project is in C#, our biggest issue is random garbage collection latency.  The memory profile of the process is many small objects and we force a garbage collection every 30 seconds to minimize any gc outliers.  This seems to work well with the exception of several longer collections that occur during the day.  I have a few questions about how to tune the system and GC to handle this load.

What is causing these periodic longer garbage collections?

Below is some production monitoring logs. Using a background clock thread (should trigger every 10ms or so) this first table records the max time gap for every 1 minute interval.

```
[13:39:00.004] updates=5,453, gaps>35ms=2, gaps>100ms=0, gaps>1sec=0, max=91.1ms
[13:40:00.005] updates=5,456, gaps>35ms=2, gaps>100ms=0, gaps>1sec=0, max=94.1ms
[13:41:00.010] updates=5,459, gaps>35ms=2, gaps>100ms=0, gaps>1sec=0, max=86.1ms
[13:42:00.007] updates=5,454, gaps>35ms=2, gaps>100ms=2, gaps>1sec=0, max=121.1ms
[13:43:00.000] updates=5,456, gaps>35ms=2, gaps>100ms=0, gaps>1sec=0, max=92.1ms
[13:44:00.000] updates=5,449, gaps>35ms=2, gaps>100ms=2, gaps>1sec=0, max=150.1ms
[13:45:00.002] updates=5,253, gaps>35ms=2, gaps>100ms=2, gaps>1sec=1, max=2347.3ms
[13:46:00.008] updates=5,452, gaps>35ms=2, gaps>100ms=1, gaps>1sec=0, max=102.1ms
[13:47:00.000] updates=5,454, gaps>35ms=2, gaps>100ms=1, gaps>1sec=0, max=109.1ms
[13:48:00.009] updates=5,455, gaps>35ms=2, gaps>100ms=1, gaps>1sec=0, max=111.1ms
[13:49:00.010] updates=5,454, gaps>35ms=2, gaps>100ms=0, gaps>1sec=0, max=94.1ms
[13:50:00.001] updates=5,455, gaps>35ms=2, gaps>100ms=0, gaps>1sec=0, max=97.1ms
[13:51:00.007] updates=5,461, gaps>35ms=2, gaps>100ms=0, gaps>1sec=0, max=84.1ms
```

The record at [13:45:00.002] shows a max=2347.3ms. In production we see several of these per day.

In the following table we record the elapsed time from the forced collection.

```
GC.Collect(1, GCCollectionMode.Forced, true);
```

This log provides the gc memory performance counters and should trigger every 30 seconds.

```
[13:42:01.272] elapsed=   85.76 ms, gcMem= 11,724.8 MB, gcCol=    833.5 MB, gen0=613, gen1=607, gen2=47 
[13:42:31.248] elapsed=   60.79 ms, gcMem= 11,736.2 MB, gcCol=    825.0 MB, gen0=614, gen1=608, gen2=47
[13:43:01.312] elapsed=  110.64 ms, gcMem= 11,791.9 MB, gcCol=  1,125.7 MB, gen0=615, gen1=609, gen2=47
[13:43:31.345] elapsed=  140.41 ms, gcMem= 11,836.7 MB, gcCol=  1,158.9 MB, gen0=616, gen1=610, gen2=47 
[13:44:01.315] elapsed=  108.77 ms, gcMem= 11,864.8 MB, gcCol=  1,004.8 MB, gen0=617, gen1=611, gen2=47  
[13:44:33.565] elapsed=2,345.37 ms, gcMem= 11,895.0 MB, gcCol=    911.7 MB, gen0=618, gen1=612, gen2=47 
[13:45:01.315] elapsed=   92.02 ms, gcMem= 11,927.0 MB, gcCol=    938.8 MB, gen0=619, gen1=613, gen2=47 
[13:45:31.331] elapsed=   96.98 ms, gcMem= 11,950.3 MB, gcCol=    941.9 MB, gen0=620, gen1=614, gen2=47
[13:46:01.316] elapsed=   82.55 ms, gcMem= 11,965.5 MB, gcCol=    855.4 MB, gen0=621, gen1=615, gen2=47 
[13:46:31.339] elapsed=  104.35 ms, gcMem= 12,012.3 MB, gcCol=  1,041.5 MB, gen0=622, gen1=616, gen2=47 
[13:47:01.348] elapsed=  109.23 ms, gcMem= 12,040.4 MB, gcCol=    914.6 MB, gen0=623, gen1=617, gen2=47
```

Here we also register a spike at [13:44:33.565] elapsed=2,345.37ms. Note that during the long gc collection, a gen2 collection was not performed.

According to the performance counters, this latency spike happens without any other significant differences to memory footprint, gc generations, and/or collected memory compared with the normal >100ms latency collections.

Here is our system performance log at the time of the latency spike.

```
+----------------+-----------+---------+---------+---------+---------------+---------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------+---------+---------+---------+----------------+----------------+---------------+------------+----------------+-------------+----------------+----------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+--------+
| Time           | TimeDelta | SysFrac | UsrFrac | TotFrac | MinWorkingSet | MaxWorkingSet | WorkingSet     | VirtualMemory   | PrivateMemory  | PagedMemory    | NonPagedMemory | PagedSysMemory | PeakVirtualMem  | PeakWorkingSet | gcCnt.0 | gcCnt.1 | gcCnt.2 | gcTotalBytes   | TotalClrMem    | Gen0Mem       | Gen1Mem    | Gen2Mem        | LargeObjMem | ReservedMem    | CommittedMem   | ContendRate | CurQueueLen | LogicalThrds | PhysicalThrds | GC%CPU |
+----------------+-----------+---------+---------+---------+---------------+---------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------+---------+---------+---------+----------------+----------------+---------------+------------+----------------+-------------+----------------+----------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+--------+
| [13:31:00.029] | 60        | 1.120   | 14.080  | 15.200  | 204,800       | 1,413,120     | 40,034,070,528 | 122,791,522,304 | 20,763,750,400 | 20,763,750,400 | 218,324        | 44,421,720     | 122,801,758,208 | 40,150,093,824 | 590     | 584     | 47      | 11,756,722,000 | 13,896,680,000 | 8,206,550,000 | 24,448,480 | 13,257,890,000 | 614,338,900 | 97,173,050,000 | 19,206,200,000 | 4           | 20          | 235          | 234           | 0.294  |
| [13:32:00.035] | 60        | 1.119   | 14.129  | 15.248  | 204,800       | 1,413,120     | 40,115,458,048 | 122,792,742,912 | 20,808,089,600 | 20,808,089,600 | 218,452        | 44,421,720     | 122,801,758,208 | 40,150,093,824 | 592     | 586     | 47      | 11,939,798,072 | 13,956,040,000 | 8,203,999,000 | 74,592,030 | 13,267,000,000 | 614,441,500 | 97,173,050,000 | 19,228,650,000 | 3           | 19          | 235          | 234           | 0.480  |
| [13:33:00.025] | 60        | 1.075   | 14.088  | 15.164  | 204,800       | 1,413,120     | 40,222,773,248 | 122,792,742,912 | 20,856,360,960 | 20,856,360,960 | 218,452        | 44,421,720     | 122,801,758,208 | 40,222,773,248 | 594     | 588     | 47      | 12,073,257,352 | 14,016,110,000 | 8,235,154,000 | 65,803,180 | 13,335,750,000 | 614,557,600 | 97,173,050,000 | 19,274,330,000 | 4           | 20          | 235          | 234           | 0.541  |
| [13:34:00.026] | 60        | 1.073   | 14.080  | 15.152  | 204,800       | 1,413,120     | 40,301,883,392 | 122,792,742,912 | 20,919,599,104 | 20,919,599,104 | 218,452        | 44,421,720     | 122,801,758,208 | 40,301,883,392 | 596     | 590     | 47      | 12,078,994,416 | 14,002,090,000 | 8,212,341,000 | 19,899,990 | 13,367,420,000 | 614,764,000 | 97,173,050,000 | 19,298,840,000 | 3           | 18          | 235          | 234           | 0.248  |
| [13:35:00.026] | 60        | 1.092   | 14.116  | 15.208  | 204,800       | 1,413,120     | 40,339,972,096 | 122,792,742,912 | 20,947,439,616 | 20,947,439,616 | 218,452        | 44,421,720     | 122,801,758,208 | 40,339,972,096 | 598     | 592     | 47      | 12,244,802,512 | 14,088,220,000 | 8,224,077,000 | 21,259,580 | 13,412,930,000 | 654,036,800 | 97,173,050,000 | 19,368,640,000 | 4           | 19          | 235          | 234           | 0.278  |
| [13:36:00.034] | 60        | 1.073   | 14.042  | 15.115  | 204,800       | 1,413,120     | 40,386,605,056 | 122,792,742,912 | 20,961,361,920 | 20,961,361,920 | 218,452        | 44,421,720     | 122,801,758,208 | 40,386,605,056 | 600     | 594     | 47      | 12,266,651,104 | 14,121,420,000 | 8,193,102,000 | 11,004,300 | 13,456,180,000 | 654,243,200 | 97,173,050,000 | 19,399,840,000 | 2           | 19          | 235          | 234           | 0.302  |
| [13:37:00.026] | 60        | 1.098   | 14.009  | 15.107  | 204,800       | 1,413,120     | 40,409,452,544 | 122,792,742,912 | 20,981,190,656 | 20,981,190,656 | 218,452        | 44,421,720     | 122,801,758,208 | 40,409,452,544 | 602     | 596     | 47      | 12,278,596,600 | 14,172,080,000 | 8,225,842,000 | 52,736,690 | 13,464,890,000 | 654,450,800 | 97,173,050,000 | 19,402,140,000 | 2           | 20          | 235          | 234           | 0.243  |
| [13:38:00.035] | 60        | 1.117   | 14.048  | 15.165  | 204,800       | 1,413,120     | 40,470,384,640 | 122,791,686,144 | 21,025,886,208 | 21,025,886,208 | 218,196        | 44,421,720     | 122,801,758,208 | 40,470,384,640 | 604     | 598     | 47      | 12,352,609,656 | 14,190,920,000 | 8,190,084,000 | 19,076,740 | 13,517,180,000 | 654,656,000 | 97,173,050,000 | 19,448,470,000 | 3           | 20          | 235          | 234           | 0.248  |
| [13:39:00.014] | 60        | 1.096   | 14.040  | 15.136  | 204,800       | 1,413,120     | 40,504,029,184 | 122,791,686,144 | 21,050,589,184 | 21,050,589,184 | 218,196        | 44,421,720     | 122,801,758,208 | 40,504,029,184 | 606     | 600     | 47      | 12,400,151,400 | 14,227,780,000 | 8,159,343,000 | 25,802,310 | 13,547,000,000 | 654,980,700 | 97,173,050,000 | 19,469,140,000 | 3           | 20          | 235          | 234           | 0.301  |
| [13:40:00.022] | 60        | 1.069   | 14.092  | 15.162  | 204,800       | 1,413,120     | 40,515,948,544 | 122,791,686,144 | 21,050,916,864 | 21,050,916,864 | 218,196        | 44,421,720     | 122,801,758,208 | 40,515,948,544 | 608     | 602     | 47      | 12,398,850,960 | 14,271,310,000 | 8,157,288,000 | 39,735,550 | 13,576,390,000 | 655,186,000 | 97,173,050,000 | 19,489,010,000 | 3           | 19          | 235          | 234           | 0.275  |
| [13:41:00.034] | 60        | 1.098   | 14.104  | 15.201  | 204,800       | 1,413,120     | 40,547,528,704 | 122,791,686,144 | 21,070,147,584 | 21,070,147,584 | 218,196        | 44,421,720     | 122,801,758,208 | 40,547,528,704 | 610     | 604     | 47      | 12,638,109,400 | 14,285,210,000 | 8,121,626,000 | 24,978,900 | 13,604,720,000 | 655,509,600 | 97,173,050,000 | 19,493,130,000 | 3           | 20          | 235          | 234           | 0.224  |
| [13:42:00.022] | 60        | 1.092   | 14.056  | 15.148  | 204,800       | 1,413,120     | 40,620,322,816 | 122,791,686,144 | 21,124,751,360 | 21,124,751,360 | 218,196        | 44,421,720     | 122,801,758,208 | 40,620,322,816 | 612     | 606     | 47      | 12,522,555,576 | 14,344,950,000 | 8,121,881,000 | 28,175,860 | 13,661,060,000 | 655,716,000 | 97,173,050,000 | 19,557,770,000 | 3           | 20          | 235          | 234           | 0.369  |
| [13:43:00.042] | 60        | 1.120   | 14.079  | 15.199  | 204,800       | 1,413,120     | 40,714,616,832 | 122,791,686,144 | 21,218,025,472 | 21,218,025,472 | 218,196        | 44,421,720     | 122,801,758,208 | 40,714,616,832 | 614     | 608     | 47      | 12,868,348,064 | 14,372,630,000 | 8,089,421,000 | 13,960,660 | 13,702,750,000 | 655,920,300 | 97,173,050,000 | 19,574,740,000 | 3           | 19          | 235          | 234           | 0.202  |
| [13:44:00.023] | 60        | 1.085   | 14.163  | 15.249  | 204,800       | 1,413,120     | 40,793,210,880 | 122,791,686,144 | 21,293,572,096 | 21,293,572,096 | 218,196        | 44,421,720     | 122,801,758,208 | 40,793,210,880 | 616     | 610     | 47      | 12,807,955,696 | 14,458,860,000 | 8,179,772,000 | 51,066,620 | 13,751,670,000 | 656,126,700 | 97,173,050,000 | 19,726,070,000 | 5           | 18          | 235          | 234           | 0.466  |
| [13:45:00.020] | 60        | 1.029   | 13.608  | 14.637  | 204,800       | 1,413,120     | 40,834,953,216 | 122,791,686,144 | 21,324,902,400 | 21,324,902,400 | 218,196        | 44,421,720     | 122,801,758,208 | 40,834,953,216 | 618     | 612     | 47      | 12,827,588,224 | 14,497,620,000 | 8,160,795,000 | 25,559,010 | 13,815,730,000 | 656,331,900 | 97,173,050,000 | 19,756,560,000 | 3           | 19          | 235          | 234           | 7.271  |
| [13:46:00.027] | 60        | 1.082   | 14.065  | 15.147  | 204,800       | 1,413,120     | 40,874,991,616 | 122,792,898,560 | 21,356,466,176 | 21,356,466,176 | 218,324        | 44,421,720     | 122,801,758,208 | 40,874,991,616 | 620     | 614     | 47      | 12,773,554,288 | 14,533,490,000 | 8,180,897,000 | 25,771,470 | 13,851,180,000 | 656,538,400 | 97,173,050,000 | 19,785,200,000 | 2           | 19          | 235          | 234           | 0.322  |
| [13:47:00.016] | 60        | 1.114   | 14.072  | 15.186  | 204,800       | 1,413,120     | 40,956,710,912 | 122,792,898,560 | 21,433,704,448 | 21,433,704,448 | 218,324        | 44,421,720     | 122,801,758,208 | 40,956,710,912 | 622     | 616     | 47      | 12,921,358,936 | 14,588,320,000 | 8,204,076,000 | 50,835,140 | 13,880,650,000 | 656,830,000 | 97,173,050,000 | 19,854,300,000 | 2           | 20          | 235          | 234           | 0.346  |
| [13:48:00.019] | 60        | 1.107   | 14.030  | 15.137  | 204,800       | 1,413,120     | 41,003,507,712 | 122,792,898,560 | 21,460,283,392 | 21,460,283,392 | 218,324        | 44,421,720     | 122,801,758,208 | 41,003,507,712 | 624     | 618     | 47      | 13,012,250,176 | 14,597,210,000 | 8,169,155,000 | 18,384,390 | 13,921,790,000 | 657,036,400 | 97,173,050,000 | 19,884,190,000 | 2           | 20          | 235          | 234           | 0.246  |
| [13:49:00.017] | 60        | 1.111   | 14.023  | 15.134  | 204,800       | 1,413,120     | 41,020,157,952 | 122,792,898,560 | 21,467,410,432 | 21,467,410,432 | 218,324        | 44,421,720     | 122,801,758,208 | 41,020,157,952 | 626     | 620     | 47      | 12,983,589,400 | 14,638,320,000 | 8,155,601,000 | 28,285,010 | 13,952,900,000 | 657,137,900 | 97,173,050,000 | 19,893,340,000 | 2           | 19          | 235          | 234           | 0.294  |
| [13:50:00.022] | 60        | 1.120   | 14.033  | 15.152  | 204,800       | 1,413,120     | 41,065,877,504 | 122,792,898,560 | 21,505,044,480 | 21,505,044,480 | 218,324        | 44,421,720     | 122,801,758,208 | 41,065,877,504 | 628     | 622     | 47      | 12,966,301,480 | 14,664,660,000 | 8,160,342,000 | 35,044,860 | 13,972,360,000 | 657,254,000 | 97,173,050,000 | 19,929,060,000 | 2           | 20          | 235          | 234           | 0.316  |
| [13:51:00.037] | 60        | 1.093   | 14.070  | 15.162  | 204,800       | 1,413,120     | 41,109,229,568 | 122,792,898,560 | 21,544,714,240 | 21,544,714,240 | 218,324        | 44,421,720     | 122,801,758,208 | 41,109,229,568 | 630     | 624     | 47      | 13,046,612,984 | 14,703,170,000 | 8,154,384,000 | 37,274,800 | 14,008,440,000 | 657,457,000 | 97,173,050,000 | 19,967,270,000 | 2           | 20          | 235          | 234           | 0.274  |
| [13:52:00.030] | 60        | 1.085   | 14.026  | 15.111  | 204,800       | 1,413,120     | 41,142,714,368 | 122,792,898,560 | 21,560,086,528 | 21,560,086,528 | 218,324        | 44,421,720     | 122,801,758,208 | 41,142,714,368 | 632     | 626     | 47      | 13,085,486,720 | 14,722,970,000 | 8,135,368,000 | 24,030,770 | 14,041,380,000 | 657,560,200 | 97,173,050,000 | 19,987,170,000 | 1           | 19          | 235          | 234           | 0.297  |
| [13:53:00.029] | 60        | 1.077   | 14.041  | 15.118  | 204,800       | 1,413,120     | 41,165,729,792 | 122,792,898,560 | 21,572,124,672 | 21,572,124,672 | 218,324        | 44,421,720     | 122,801,758,208 | 41,165,729,792 | 634     | 628     | 47      | 13,182,848,552 | 14,748,780,000 | 8,116,007,000 | 23,681,860 | 14,067,340,000 | 657,764,400 | 97,173,050,000 | 19,999,100,000 | 1           | 20          | 235          | 234           | 0.227  |
| [13:54:00.030] | 60        | 1.087   | 14.097  | 15.183  | 204,800       | 1,413,120     | 41,212,456,960 | 122,792,898,560 | 21,617,262,592 | 21,617,262,592 | 218,324        | 44,421,720     | 122,801,758,208 | 41,212,456,960 | 636     | 630     | 47      | 13,357,287,176 | 14,781,100,000 | 8,099,477,000 | 20,468,650 | 14,102,660,000 | 657,969,700 | 97,173,050,000 | 20,043,010,000 | 2           | 20          | 235          | 234           | 0.269  |
| [13:55:00.033] | 60        | 1.090   | 14.024  | 15.114  | 204,800       | 1,413,120     | 41,235,304,448 | 122,792,898,560 | 21,632,643,072 | 21,632,643,072 | 218,324        | 44,421,720     | 122,801,758,208 | 41,235,304,448 | 638     | 632     | 47      | 13,274,559,640 | 14,850,320,000 | 8,144,056,000 | 26,831,810 | 14,165,200,000 | 658,292,200 | 97,173,050,000 | 20,059,910,000 | 2           | 20          | 235          | 234           | 0.336  |
| [13:56:00.025] | 60        | 1.090   | 14.003  | 15.093  | 204,800       | 1,413,120     | 41,277,251,584 | 122,792,898,560 | 21,665,263,616 | 21,665,263,616 | 218,324        | 44,421,720     | 122,801,758,208 | 41,277,251,584 | 640     | 634     | 47      | 13,343,955,968 | 14,872,170,000 | 8,106,031,000 | 20,415,720 | 14,193,260,000 | 658,496,300 | 97,173,050,000 | 20,063,000,000 | 1           | 19          | 235          | 234           | 0.225  |
| [13:57:00.023] | 60        | 1.127   | 14.558  | 15.685  | 204,800       | 1,413,120     | 41,018,687,488 | 122,792,898,560 | 21,709,570,048 | 21,709,570,048 | 218,324        | 44,421,720     | 122,801,758,208 | 41,322,450,944 | 642     | 636     | 48      | 11,972,380,824 | 14,922,300,000 | 8,184,630,000 | 95,170,150 | 14,193,260,000 | 633,870,800 | 97,173,050,000 | 20,096,390,000 | 6           | 20          | 232          | 231           | 0.592  |
| [13:58:00.032] | 60        | 1.074   | 14.149  | 15.223  | 204,800       | 1,413,120     | 41,062,780,928 | 122,809,479,168 | 21,752,737,792 | 21,752,737,792 | 218,452        | 44,421,720     | 122,809,479,168 | 41,322,450,944 | 644     | 638     | 48      | 12,016,674,992 | 14,881,730,000 | 8,209,373,000 | 39,635,030 | 14,208,120,000 | 633,974,100 | 97,173,050,000 | 20,177,100,000 | 3           | 19          | 232          | 231           | 0.358  |
| [13:59:00.031] | 60        | 1.019   | 13.970  | 14.990  | 204,800       | 1,413,120     | 41,064,423,424 | 122,809,479,168 | 21,752,930,304 | 21,752,930,304 | 218,452        | 44,421,720     | 122,817,601,536 | 41,322,450,944 | 646     | 640     | 48      | 11,809,759,384 | 14,862,300,000 | 8,142,180,000 | 19,593,650 | 14,208,530,000 | 634,177,200 | 97,173,050,000 | 20,179,600,000 | 2           | 20          | 232          | 231           | 0.196  |
| [14:00:00.036] | 60        | 1.056   | 13.984  | 15.041  | 204,800       | 1,413,120     | 41,067,610,112 | 122,809,544,704 | 21,755,564,032 | 21,755,564,032 | 218,580        | 44,421,720     | 122,817,601,536 | 41,322,450,944 | 648     | 642     | 48      | 11,906,742,832 | 14,855,660,000 | 8,086,772,000 | 12,748,120 | 14,208,530,000 | 634,381,300 | 97,173,050,000 | 20,182,000,000 | 2           | 20          | 232          | 231           | 0.179  |
+----------------+-----------+---------+---------+---------+---------------+---------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------+---------+---------+---------+----------------+----------------+---------------+------------+----------------+-------------+----------------+----------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+--------+
```

Can someone explain the extra load that is driving these random longer collections?

Also:

> 1) Are there any additional metrics we can monitor to understand these latency spikes?
>
> 2) Are there any other strategies we should use to reduce the duration of these latency spikes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a test program to reproduce this? or is this production code

Comment: This is production code.  We are processing large numbers of udp data packets.  Any thoughts on how to investigate?

Comment: Do you do a full GC or do you just do a Gen1 or Gen2 GC? Have you looked at the Large Object Heap, and how it fills and is collected? Starting with the 4.0 runtime, you can protect regions of code from GC interruption. Have you looked at that as an alternate strategy? Do you load test scripts you can use to try and repro this in a lesd-than-prod environment?

Comment: Oh, how do you decide when to do your forced GCs? What you want to do is invoke the GC at a time when the heap is reasonably quiescent. If you force a GC at a time when there a lot of transient objects on the heap, all those objects will be promoted to Gen2. Gen1 collections are much cheaper than Gen2 or Gen3

Comment: Thanks for looking into this for me...the above log shows a gc 1 collection is randomly spiking in latency.  Note this only happens a few times a day.  ie not very often relative to the amount of data we are processing.  Would the forced collection matter on gc generation? Ie Should I change the gen param to 2 and run again?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to answer your question...currently we somewhat arbitrarily call GC every 30 seconds.

Comment: if you have hard latency requirements, you've started out from the wrong starting point. You're not going to meet them from something like .NET. And GC.Collect only really has a place in benchmarks and (sometimes) unit tests.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to read my post.  I treat GC.Collect as part of the 95% 5% rule.  For the vast majority of programming problems the GC will be better at this process.  However, this is likely one of the exceptions.  If we could replace a longer collection with many smaller more frequent collections that would be a performance win for this process.  Do you know why these specific spikes are happening but do not show up in the traditional performance counters?